# C# create version of struct (inheritance or otherwise) that has fields renamed

Tags: c#, inheritance, struct, alias

Let's say I have a C# struct of which I want to create a derived version that is functionally equivalent but has some Properties or Functions renamed. How would I best do that to have the derived version not perform any worse and avoiding code duplication in the process?

To be more specific, I have a struct Vector3 with properties X, Y, Z and plenty of functions and want to have a structLlaVec with the names of the properties changed to Longitude, Latitude and Altitude, potentially also the documentation of these properties changed.

Is there any way other than duplicating the implementation of the struct to do this?

Comment: What way are you looking for? Something what automatically determine "look, X is Longtitude"?

Comment: You cannot inherit of structs in c#

Comment: No -- you'll have to create a new struct one way or the other. You can supply user-defined conversion operators to seamlessly go from a `Vector3` to your struct (and vice versa), but those conversion do have performance impact if they're done frequently.

Comment: Sounds like your struct is for cartesian coordinates ... not spherical ... are you sure you can simply use the same "plenty of functions" ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use inheritance but use encapsulation.

In other words, create a new type that wraps the struct you have and delegate your new functions or properties to the properties of the wrapped struct.

For instance:

```
struct LlaVec
{
    private readonly Vector3 _v;

    public LlaVec( Vector3 v ) 
    {
        _v = v;
    }

    public int Altitude { get { return _v.Z; }}
}
```

Comment: I thought of that, but am concerned about degraded performance. Would such a property still get inlined?

Comment: Be concerned about performance when you have a working solution. 1. Make it. 2. Make it work. 3. Make it work correctly. 4. Make it work fast.